# I mistakenly submitted a DS-160 application for a visa I already have. Could this be a problem?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, applications

Back in 2018 I applied for a tourist **B2** visa to United States. I successfully obtained the document and subsequently travelled to US.

This year I am required to travel to US for business, and hence require a **B1**. I have filled out and **submitted** the **DS-160** application (including the details of the previous visa number etc).

However, after doing so, I looked at my passport again, and as it turns out, the previously granted visa is in fact of type '**B1/B2**'. It is valid for another 9 years, and for multiple entries.

I now realise my mistake; as it turns out I did not require any more documentation to travel. However, did submitting the **additional DS-160** form have any effect on my status?

I know that one cannot delete a submitted DS-160, and I have not booked/attended an interview at an US embassy. Am I therefore safe to ignore the extra application? Would that information be available, or could it at all **cause any problems**, at the port of entry?

Comment: Maybe calling US embassy -and telling what happened- could be an option

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately the local embassies do not answer 'visa related questions' over the phone. I will attempt other routes...

Answer (score 1):

The visa application process cannot be completed until you appear for an interview with a consular officer. You should probably cancel your interview just to make it official.

According to [this Quora Q/A web page](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-delete-DS-160-form-after-submission)

> You don’t need to delete the form. Just cancel the interview
>   appointment, if you made one. Eventually, if the submission isn’t
>   used, the system will probably delete it. Not showing up will not
>   count as a refusal.

and

> You can cancel an interview appointment by signing-in, going to the
>   "My Account" home page, and selecting either the "Cancel Appointment"
>   or "Reschedule Appointment" links.

If you haven’t take any appointment or payment of fees than after 30 days of submission the DS160 form automatically vanishes. It should not affect your current visa.

Comment: Thank you AussieJoe, that's reassuring... I have not scheduled the interview, so I suppose I will check if the application does indeed get deleted after 30 days. I looked at my previous one, from 2018, and I can still see it on the system, however that could be due to it being 'acted upon'.